# What's wrong with Chrome's xslt processor? Sometimes blank output

Tags: google-chrome, xslt, svg

Some time ago I have written an XSLT "program" that converts Eagle (PCB CAD) files to SVG. It runs on Firefox and Internet Explorer.

However, on current version of Chrome and Chromium, it will sometimes not work.

This one works and shows the schematic as SVG:

http://www.tu-chemnitz.de/~heha/enas/STS%20Multiplex/MFC-Verteiler.zip/MFC4.sch?as=SVG

Although very similar and even shorter, this one will show a blank screen:

http://www.tu-chemnitz.de/~heha/enas/UDX5114N.zip/sm5.sch?as=SVG

Both example URLs download genuine Eagle XML schematic files and let the browser do the conversion to SVG without Javascript.

Does someone has a clue how I can track down the problem, if even possible? (Is there something like an XSLT debugger for Chrome?)

In case of importance, I use Windows 7 64 bit German.

Comment: The XSLT processor in Chrome is libxslt so you can use xsltproc or any other tool incorporating libxslt to test the transformation outside of the browser.

Comment: Okay, xsltproc says:

xsltApplyXSLTTemplate: A potential infinite template recursion was detected.
You can adjust maxTemplateVars (--maxvars) in order to raise the maximum number of variables/params (currently set to 15000).

Comment: Pardon: Stackoverflow removed important parts of last answer. … I tried "--maxvars 1000000" with success. So the next question is: How can I inject that parameter into Chrome's invocation of xsltproc?

Comment: If you save the result of xsltproc to a file and load that in Chrome, does it render the result as you want? As for changing the recursion limit for libxslt inside of Chrome, I am not sure there is a way.

Comment: Surprisingly, no one libxslt generated SVG file can be displayed in any browser. No idea why. However, giving "--maxvars 1000000" or "--maxvars 100000" emits SVG content as such, whereas processing the problematic one without "--maxvars" will emit nothing but some 100 lines of strange error messages.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure it is a problem with Chrome, it seems your stylesheet sometimes generates HTML with embedded SVG and sometimes tries to output an SVG document but only gets the SVG namespace right on the root element and some container elements, the content elements are then created in no namespace e.g. end up as `<text font-size="2.1336" transform="translate(13.97,154.94)scale(1,-1)" text-anchor="end" fill="#088" xmlns="">black</text>`. So wherever you want to output SVG elements with XSLT you should make sure you output them with the right namespace, either using literal result elements with e.g. `<text xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">..</text>` where the namespace could also be present on an ancestor of the literal result element in the stylesheet or by using `<xsl:element namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" name="text">...</xsl:element>`, where the namespace declaration could also be present on an ancestor element of the `xsl:element` in the stylesheet. Putting the namespace on an ancestor element of the result tree you generate in a different template causes the creation of element in no namespace.

For Firefox your stylesheet works differently and inserts a prefix (`name="{$svgpre}g"`) for those SVG elements where the prefix together with the existing namespace declaration on the root puts the elements in the right namespace. Not sure why IE and Edge render the result, other than they seem to put everything into an HTML wrapper and ignore the namespaces in HTML5 fashion.

Answer (score 0):

I know my XSLT: Generating SVG namespace for Firefox and *not* generating SVG namespace for Internet Explorer was the *one and only* way to bring it to work on both browsers. Moreover, as the first given example works well in Chrome (and most of my schematics), Chrome seems to have no problem with the missing name space, it's IE compatible, and I expect there is another reason why the second example won't work.